# Marketing Cloud super messages consumption under specific circumstances

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know the answers to the questions regarding the consumption of the super messages mentioned below?

1. Are super messages consumed when an email send is skipped because of the exclusion script evaluated to true? I know that super messages are consumed when an email send is skipped because of the AMPscript's RaiseError function, so wondering if it works the same for the exclusion scripts.
2. I know that the SMS send will be skipped when the message is empty. But will the super messages be consumed in that case?

Would appreciate any insights. Thank you!

Comment: To answer the first one - no, if send is skipped because of an exclusion script, you won’t be charged.

Comment: if an SMS is not sent out of the system it will not consume an SM